# How to open .max files

Tags: 3d-models, file-formats, 123d-catch

I need help opening a `.max` file a friend sent me. The thing is, I don't have Alias Maya. Well, a copy of Alias Maya that works anyway.

Are there any other file openers that I can use? Or do I have to get Maya to open the file? Would Alias Maya open the file? I don't want to get download 1.3 GB and discover that there is 15 MB file opener.

Is there a file converter maybe? That converts `.max` to, maybe, `.obj`?

Comment: I believe the best tool for such conversion is 3DMax itself. I also tried [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+max+to+stl) which returned me some worth-to-check results.

Comment: If you want to use it for 3d printing then I suggest you to ask your friend to export it to STL format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try import it with [blender](https://www.blender.org/download/). It's a free software which should be able to import the files.

First thing is to go the the File->User Preferences->Add Ons tab. In the Import-Export section, enable the 3DS Add-on.

After that you can export it to the desired format. Before exporting you must select the model/mesh you want to export. Otherwise nothing will be exported. The obj exporter is enabled by default in blender.

Comment: So I must export the file in Maya first?

Comment: Or import in Blender?

Comment: Blender should be able to import the .max file directly after activating the shipped 3DS Add-on ;)

Comment: Ah. I see. How big is blender?

Comment: Blender is about 100 megabytes at the moment. So not to big in my opinion

Comment: Oh woah. I was expecting it to be atleast 1gb. This is the whole file right?

Comment: Jep. In the 100 mb download is everything you need. Just don't forget to activate the 3DS Add-on. I use blender a lot in my 3d printing projects...

Comment: Oh great stuff. Thank you for the insight. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Tell me something. Is a .max file the same as a .3ds file?

Comment: These are two different file formats from the same company (Autodesk). But blender should be able to import both

Comment: I installed blender, and went to add ons, and saw the .3ds file plugin was already on. I then looked for my file and didnt see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there another plugin?

Comment: Have you had any luck importing .max files in blender?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39557/discussion-between-gipsyd-and-salomonderossi).

Comment: `.3ds` is not `.max`. Try converting online