# How to enlarge a Sketchup Model

Tags: 3d-models, resolution, support-structures

I have moved forward with the whole [.max thing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/how-to-open-max-files). It's on the back burner. But not as critical now. I have found a Sketchup model of the model I want. But it is ridiculously small (0.17 m long by 0.10 m wide!).

How do I enlarge it to fit my dimensions as a whole?

Comment: You could try the scale function (try **s** on the keyboard). There's probably a metric conversion issue, so try applying the 25.4 rule to your model. If the model is in mm, but your environment is in inches, then multiply by 25.4. If reverse, divide by 25.4.

Comment: I would not consider 0.17m (=17cm) to be ridiculously small. That's pretty large for 3D printers. The ".max thing" seems wholly irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I included the .max thing because the original model I wanted was in .max format, but I found the same model in a sketchup model.

Comment: You're right. 17 cm is quite large for printing. I wanted to upscale the model because it is uncomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cura middle button in bottom
[image]

Comment: Ah. I see. Thats what I needed. Now I can work on my model nicely now =D